# convert spark column of nested json into string

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm relatively new to spark/scala and i've got the following problem i'm hoping you can help me out with. In order for my hashing algorithm to work i need to convert an array type field into a string. The schema below is similar to what i'm dealing with:

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| records         | Partition      |
+-----------------+----------------+
| [{data:[{...}..]| 20200101       |
+-----------------+----------------+
| [{data:[{...}..]| 20200102       |
+-----------------+----------------+

The field types are: {records: array, partition: string}
```

All i want is to convert the record field into a string, in the vein of:

```
[{data:[{...}..] --> "[{data:[{...}..]"
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to convert an ArrayType to a StringType with that literal content?. I think it would be better to parse the Array and create different columns in order to apply any hashing algorithm. Otherwise you will need to parse the "[{data:[{...}..]" string.

Comment: I'm afraid in this instance I need the literal content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to have your data schema (using `df.printSchema`). But with simple example I managed to do it using a simple cast like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val castDf = df.withColumn("ArrrayToString", $"myColName".cast(StringType))
```

Comment: This is the approach I ended up using. Thanks!